# SSIS : Passing XML file content to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Aim: To create a SSIS package to pass content of an XML file as parameter to a stored procedure in SQL.

What i have done till now: Created an SSIS package which has a For each loop container to loop through a folder which has many XML files. The container has a file System task which should copy content of XML files in that folder to a variable. After file system task it executes a Sql task where it executes a stored procedure and passes the parameter containing XML file content to this stored procedure

Where i am stuck at the moment: When i execute my SSIS package it is giving me an error where the file system task does not execute and it says

> "Variable is used as a source or destination and is empty"

This error shows up after execution and delay validation is set to true

I have searched and found that if delay validation is set to true then it might fix but this happens after execution

Can any one help me as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please Read [How to Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: @KrunalShah Rather than downvoting it would be better to specifically point out what is wrong with the question.

Comment: there is too much that i cant specifically point it out over here. for this purpose @stackoverflow has made a very good web page about how to ask good question which specifically covers all of the points.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current problem is around the "file system task" and has nothing to do with XML or stored procedures yet right? Can you explain in detail how you set up the file system task?

Comment: The File System Task has no mechanism for loading file content. Take a look at this tutorial for loading text from a file into a variable, which is what you're trying to do. https://svangasql.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/how-to-read-a-flat-file-to-variable-ssis-script-task/

Comment: @digital.aaron thanks . That is what I am trying to achieve. I am new to SSIS so was not sure if that is the right way to do